# select2 - how preselecting multiple options that receive data from an AJAX remote source

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a modal that has two 'behaviors', one to create new record and another to edit existing record, depending on which button is clicked (new / edit).

When you click edit, the record data (users table) is loaded 'along' with the child records (permissions table).

During modal loading, the select2 is initialized:

```
let $select2user    = $(".select2user");

$select2user.select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'getUsersWithPermissions.php',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                search: params.term,
                page: params.page || 1
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            data.page = data.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.items.map(function (item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.name
                    };
                })
            }
        },
        cache: true,
        delay: 250
    },
    multiple: true
});
```

Everything works fine, except when I click edit a record.

The inputs form (modal) are filled in correctly with the registration data, however, I cannot pre-select multiple options from child records (permissions table).

I tried to use 'append', but it ends up generating duplicate options.

```
$.each( value, function( permissions, permission ) {
  console.log(permission['name']); // ok
  let newOption = new Option(permission['name'], permission['id'], false, true);
  $select2user.append(newOption);
});
$select2user.trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#selectlist").select2();
  
  var _selectedValues = [];
  _selectedValues.push('1');
  _selectedValues.push('5');
  _selectedValues.push('8');
  $("#selectlist").select2().val(_selectedValues).trigger("change");
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectlist" class="form-control" name="selectList[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
  <option value="7">Seven</option>
  <option value="8">Eight</option>
  <option value="9">Nine</option>
  <option value="10">Ten</option>
</select>
```

You can try like this, to set the values in select2.

```
var _selectedValues = [];
_selectedValues.push('1');
_selectedValues.push('2');
_selectedValues.push('3');
$("#selectlist").select2().val(_selectedValues).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thanks for the collaboration, however, your suggestion works for 'static' options, but unfortunately, it does not work for 'dynamically' loaded (remote source ajax) options.

Comment: As you mentioned, you are getting duplicate options (by append), instead of append, add the id to array and execute this code in ajax success block,